# Why does my code not work when I try to merge two (.txt) files into another (.txt) file?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, printwriter

I have two .txt file (file1.txt and file2.txt). In these file there are some lines of character. My intention is to merge the content of these two file into another file(file3.txt). My code is below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("file3.txt");
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));


        String line = br1.readLine();
        while(line!=null){
            pw.println(line);
            br1.readLine();
        }

        line = br2.readLine();
        while (line!=null) {
            pw.println(line);
            br2.readLine();

        }

        pw.flush();
        pw.close();

        br1.close();
        br2.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaIoProject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaIoProject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }     
}
```

When compile there is no error. After running when i try to see expected output inside (file3.txt) it does not show anything and mouse pointer change to processing. Why this happens. Where is the missing part that i forgot to add or which part should i edit and why.. Need your help.. thanks.

Comment: What do you think `br1.readLine();` does, _by itself_?

Comment: Because you are not adding them together? you are just opening and reading them

Comment: I think it returns the next line . isn't it?

Comment: And what do you do with that line?

Comment: I got it.. I forgot to re assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Lots of code you have repeated multiple times in your implementation. You can
>   simply create a method and invoke it as per filename.

```
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("file3.txt");
    readAndWrite(pw, "file1.txt");
    readAndWrite(pw, "file2.txt");

    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
```

and this is definition of readAndWrite method. Also correct the loop.

```
private static void readAndWrite(PrintWriter pw, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line!=null) {
        pw.println(line);
        line =br.readLine();    
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You miss to reassign the value for line in the loop so you get an infinite loop.

Change both while loops:

```
 while (line!=null) {
        pw.println(line);
        line =br2.readLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the assignment. So You can try something like this.

```
 String line ="";
 while((line=br1.readLine())!=null){
      pw.println(line);
 }

 line = "";
 while ((line=br2.readLine())!=null) {
     pw.println(line);
 }
```